# Why can't if part not executed in laravel 5 controller method?

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function index1()
{

   // $g = Request::input('grade');
    //$s = Request::input('subject');
        $g=$_POST['grade'];
        $s=$_POST['subject'];



if(strcmp($g,'Select A Grade')==0 || strcmp($s,'Select A Subject')==0){

    if(strcmp($s,'Select A Subject')!=0){
   // Session::flash('msg', 'Please select the Subject.');
     return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    }
    else if(strcmp($g,'Select A Grade')!=0){
    // Session::flash('msg', 'Please select the Grade.');
     return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    }


}

else{

        $u = DB::table('upldtbls')->where('grade',$g)->where('subject',$s)->get();


        return view('2Eng',compact('u'));
}

}
```

Above is the controller method. Main else part executed correctly. But main if part not executed I guess. In main if condition I want to stay on the same page if drop box values are equal to that. Can any one figure out this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you what to do:

```
    if(strcmp($s,'Select A Subject') !== 0 ){
   // Session::flash('msg', 'Please select the Subject.');
     return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    }
    else if(strcmp($g,'Select A Grade') !== 0 ){
    // Session::flash('msg', 'Please select the Grade.');
     return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    }
```

Ps.
Don't use $_POST, use this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

And for validation its more convenient to use:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Comment: I have updated the answer. Still I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Make it as it was before, and just change '==0' to '!=0'

Comment: I have updated again. Same problem will arise. Actually, I need to do this ==0 for that.